# Circular import entre views y models django

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework, django-views

estoy teniendo problemas para resolver esto.

Tengo una funcion en views.py que es el UserManager, eso esta importado en models.py para utilizarlo. Pero a su vez tengo que importar el modelo User a views.py por lo que se genera este error.

Estuve buscando algunas alternativas pero no se me ocurre como hacer un import sin hacer un import jaja.

models.py

```
from .views import UserManager

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    objects = UserManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import User

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    
    def list(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()  
        return Response({'users': users})
```

Comment: Por qué escribes ".views" en lugar de simplemente "views"?

Answer (score 0):

Con declarar la clase *UserManager* directamente en *models.py* pude solucionarlo.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.